# Что нам стоит дом построить - синонимичные поговорки

Tags: лексика, фразеология

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пословицы, поговорки, крылатые слова, сходные по смыслу с "Что нам стоит дом построить". Точнее уместные в ситуации "Вздумала я то-то сделать". Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Не боги горшки обжигают*; *глаза боятся, а руки делают*; *лиха беда начало*.

Answer (score 2):

Поговорка с продолжением: Что нам стоит дом построить, нарисуем - будем жить.